# When, if ever, will NPM restore dependencies published after the dependent package?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-publish, npm-update, npm-version

*Assume all references in package.json are ^1.0.0 and I only bump the patch version.*

I have A dependent on B dependent on C: A > B > C. I restore A and notice that the version of C I get is published after B. I expected the latest version of C *that was published before B* would be restored, but I actually got a version of C published after B.

I then published a vacuous patch of C and tried to upgrade A expecting to see the new version of C. However nothing changed; The version of C restored with A was the same version I got before I published a new version of C.

So, does NPM consider when packages were published when restoring dependencies of the form ^1.0.0?

---

> As of npm@2.6.1, the npm update will only inspect top-level packages. Prior versions of npm would also recursively inspect all dependencies. To get the old behavior, use npm --depth 9999 update.

I'm running 6.4.1 so I was not getting the recursive behavior by default. Using the depth flag, I see C is updated to the new version.

However, that still doesn't explain why a version of C published after B was synchronized in the first place; When I first sync, even if I don't pass a depth flag, NPM has to recurse all dependencies. During that initial sync, what policy is it applying?

Now, if I delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` I consistently get the new version of C. It's as if npm has remembered that I previously ran npm update with the depth flag however I find no record that I did that in packages.json as C is not listed in A's packages.json.

Answer (score 0):

*The behavior of `npm` makes more sense if I assume its designers were trying to reduce network traffic to npm.org.*

`npm install` > `v2.6.1` will satisfy indirect dependencies using the cache if possible even if more recent satisfactory versions have been published to npm.org; `npm install` will **not** check if there are more recently published versions of cached packages.

There are two ways to force npm to check the server for the most recent package versions: (1) use `--depth 9999` or (2) delete the cache using `npm cache clear --froce`.

I think `npm publish` should locally cache the new package...